# Check over hand values for single-suited Mahjong

Tags: code-golf, game

[Mahjong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahjong) is a tile game that is immensely popular in Asia. It is typically played with four players, and the goal of the game is to be the first person to complete a valid hand using the tiles. In mahjong there are three tile suits plus honour tiles — for this challenge we will only consider hands formed using tiles from a single suit.

Tiles are numbered from `1` to `9`, and there are exactly four copies of each tile. A valid hand consists of four sets of three and a pair, for a total of fourteen tiles.

A set of three can be either:

- A triplet, three of the same tile (e.g. `444`), or
- A sequence of three consecutive tiles (e.g. `123` or `678` but not `357`). Sequences do not wrap (so `912` is invalid).

A pair is simply two identical tiles (e.g. `55`).

## The challenge

Given a valid hand of fourteen tiles, determine its score based on the following criteria:

```
Condition                Description                                 Point/s
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Straight                 Contains the sequences 123 456 789          1
Identical sequences      Contains two identical sequences            1
All simples              Only 2-8, no 1s or 9s                       1
All sequences            All sets of three are sequences             1
All triplets             All sets of three are triplets              2
Flush                    Single-suit hand (always applies)           5
```

<sup>*(Scoring here is based off Japanese mahjong rules, but heavily simplified to make the spec less messy.)*</sup>

The score of a hand is the sum of points for the conditions it satisfies. If a hand can be decomposed in more than one way, take the highest scoring decomposition.

The input hand is guaranteed to be valid, i.e. fourteen tiles from 1 to 9 and each tile appearing at most four times, and may be assumed to be already sorted. Input is a list of digits (as a string or a single flat list of integers) via STDIN, function argument or command line. Output may be to STDOUT or return value.

## Test cases

```
22233355777888  ->  8  # 222 333 55 777 888, flush + all simp. + all trip.
11112345678999  ->  6  # 111 123 456 789 99, flush + straight
11123456788999  ->  5  # 111 234 567 88 999, flush only (no straight)
23344455566788  ->  7  # 234 345 456 567 88, flush + all simp. + all seq.
33334444555566  ->  8  # 33 345 345 456 456, flush + all simp. + all seq. + identical seq.
11122233377799  ->  7  # 111 222 333 777 99, flush + all trip. (no identical seq.)
12344556678889  ->  8  # 123 456 456 789 88, flush + all seq. + straight + identical seq.
11344556678999  ->  5  # 11 345 456 678 999, flush only (no identical seq.)
22233344455566  ->  8  # 222 333 444 555 66, flush + all simp. + all trip.
11112233344555  ->  5  # 111 123 234 345 55, flush only
```

For the fifth example, despite having two pairs of identical sequences, only one needs to be present to attain the point. The decomposition `345 345 345 345 66` would score the same, while `333 345 444 555 66` scores worse.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the solution in the fewest bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny/) apply.

---

*Related challenge: [What are you waiting for? (A mahjong solver)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39896/what-are-you-waiting-for-a-mahjong-solver)*

Answer (score 1):

## J (241 byes)

You need the latest version of [J](http://jsoftware.com/) installed.

```
i=:>:@i.9
q=:,/^:4>@:{(i.9);(i.;i.;i.;i.)16
s=:3 :'(>./((5+([:(*./)(3*i.3)&e.)+(-.@:(-:~.))+((*./)@:(6&>:))+2*((*./)@:(6&<)))"1(}."1(y(-:/:~"1)"1((([:{&(i,.i){.),[:,/[:{&(((>:@i.7)+"0 1(i.3)),|:3 9$i)}.)"1 q))#q)))+([:(*./)[:-.((1 9)&e.))y'
```

---

Call the function `s` with a list of integers. For example, the following example script verifies the test cases above:

```
#!/usr/bin/jconsole
i=:>:@i.9
q=:,/^:4>@:{(i.9);(i.;i.;i.;i.)16
s=:3 :'(>./((5+([:(*./)(3*i.3)&e.)+(-.@:(-:~.))+((*./)@:(6&>:))+2*((*./)@:(6&<)))"1(}."1(y(-:/:~"1)"1((([:{&(i,.i){.),[:,/[:{&(((>:@i.7)+"0 1(i.3)),|:3 9$i)}.)"1 q))#q)))+([:(*./)[:-.((1 9)&e.))y'


echo (s 2 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 7 7 7 8 8 8)=8
echo (s 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9)=6
echo (s 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 9 9 9)=5
echo (s 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 7 8 8)=7
echo (s 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6)=8
echo (s 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 7 7 7 9 9)=7
echo (s 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 8 8 9)=8
echo (s 1 1 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 9 9 9)=5
echo (s 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6)=8
echo (s 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5)=5

exit''
```